# React pass function as prop

Tags: reactjs

I have a basic React app with a function in the `App.js` component to pass down as a prop for subsequent components to handle moving a book between shelves.

When I pass the function down one level, from `App.js` to `ListBooks.js` to be passed on the `Books.js` component which is where the user will select the new shelf and trigger the API call and state update, this works fine.

However when I then try to do the same from `App.js` > `SearchBooks.js` > `Book.js` it does not seem to work.

What I expect is for the `updateShelf` function to be called to update the book and the state.

Apologies for 'wall of code' if there's too much there, just not sure exactly where the issue is.

EDIT:

As suggested in comments, here is a CodeSandbox version:
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/richardcurteis/myreads-udacity

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ListBooks from './ListBooks'
import SearchBooks from './SearchBooks'
import * as BooksAPI from './utils/BooksAPI'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

class BooksApp extends Component {

  state = {
    books: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BooksAPI.getAll()
    .then((books) => {
      this.setState(() => ({
        books
      }))
    })
  }

  updateShelf = (book, shelf) => {
    this.state.books.forEach(b => {
      if(b.id === book.id) {
        b.shelf = shelf
        this.setState((currentState) => ({
          books: currentState.books
        }))
        BooksAPI.update(book, shelf)
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
          <ListBooks
          books={this.state.books}
          onUpdateShelf={this.updateShelf}
          />
        )} />
        <Route exact path='/search' render={() => (
          <SearchBooks
          onUpdateShelf={this.updateShelf}
          />
        )} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default BooksApp
```

`SearchBooks.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as BooksAPI from './utils/BooksAPI'
import Book from './Book';

export default class SearchBooks extends Component {

    state = {
        query: '',
        books: []
    }

    updateQuery(query) {
        this.setState(() => ({
            books: [],
            query: query
        }))
        this.bookSearch(query)
    }

    bookSearch(e) {
        if (e.length > 0) BooksAPI.search(e)
        .then(books => this.setState(currentState => ({
            books: books
        })));
     }


    render() {

        const { query, books } = this.state
        const { onUpdateShelf } = this.props

        return(
            <div className="search-books">
                <div className="search-books-bar">
                  <a className="close-search" >Close</a>
                  <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Search by title, author or subject"
                        value={query}
                        onChange={(event) => this.updateQuery(event.target.value)}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="search-books-results">
                  <ol className="books-grid">
                    <li>
                      { !books.error ? (
                        books.map((book) => (
                          <Book
                            key={book.id}
                            book={book}
                            updateShelf={onUpdateShelf}
                             />
                          ))
                        ) : (
                          <h4>"{query}", is not a valid search</h4>
                        )}
                    </li>
                  </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`Book.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


class Book extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        book: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }    

    render() {

        const { book, updateShelf } = this.props

        return(
            <div key={book.id} className="book">
                <div className="book-top">
                    <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${book.imageLinks.thumbnail})` }}></div>
                        <div className="book-shelf-changer"> 
                            <select value={book.shelf ? book.shelf : 'none'} onChange={(e) => updateShelf(book, e.target.value)}>
                                <option disabled >Move to...</option>
                                <option value="currentlyReading" >Currently Reading</option>
                                <option value="wantToRead" >Want to Read</option>
                                <option value="read" >Read</option>
                                <option value="none" >None</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
                <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Book
```

Just for reference:

`ListBooks.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import './App.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Book from './Book'

const shelves = [
  {
    key: 'currentlyReading',
    name: 'Currently Reading'
  },
  {
    key: 'wantToRead',
    name: 'Want To Read'
  },
  {
    key: 'read',
    name: 'Read'
  }
];

class ListBooks extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
       books: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
       onUpdateShelf: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

    render() {

        const { books, onUpdateShelf } = this.props

        function getBooksForShelf(shelfKey) {
          return books.filter(book => book.shelf === shelfKey);
        }

        return(
            <div className="app">
              <div className="list-books">
                <div className="list-books-title">
                  <h1>My Reads</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="list-books-content">
                  <div>
                    { shelves.map((shelf) => (
                      <div key={shelf.key} className="bookshelf">
                        <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{shelf.name}</h2>
                        { getBooksForShelf(shelf.key).length === 0 ? (
                          <div>
                            <h4>No books in this shelf</h4>
                          </div>
                        ) : (
                          <div className="bookshelf-books">
                            <ol className="books-grid">
                              <li>
                                { getBooksForShelf(shelf.key).map((book) => (
                                 <Book key={book.id}
                                     book={book}
                                     updateShelf={onUpdateShelf}/>
                                  ))}
                              </li>
                            </ol>
                          </div> 
                        )}
                      </div>
                    )) }
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <Link
                     to='/search'
                      className="open-search">
                      Find a Book
                  </Link>
              </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ListBooks
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? do you get any errors in console or what's the behavior? Maybe you could create an example on CodeSandbox?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk. Not used it before but I think this should be right

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/richardcurteis/myreads-udacity

Comment: So how do I reproduce the error?

Comment: There is no error. That's the thing. If you go to the home page you can select a new shelf for the rendered books with the button on each object. If you go to the search page and type in 'poetry' for example, the same change does not happen for the books there

Comment: The first thing I see that you didn't install `react-router`. Try `npm i react-router`

Comment: I have `'react-router-dom'` installed

Comment: you need both react-router and react-router-dom. That's why code sandbox throws an error.

Comment: Add into index.js?

Comment: no, just installed. `Route` uses `withRouter` which is in `react-router` package. Update Code-Sandbox example if you can.

Comment: Ok done that. Still see that error though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171790/discussion-between-tomasz-mularczyk-and-rich-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed it's not a problem with the prop passing but rather with updating the state. Here is the modified code that seems to work:

```
  updateShelf = (book, shelf) => {
    const bookFromState = this.state.books.find(b => b.id === book.id);
    if (bookFromState) {
      // update existing
      bookFromState.shelf = shelf;
      this.setState(currentState => ({
        books: currentState.books
      }));
      BooksAPI.update(book, shelf);
    } else {
      // add new one
      this.setState(prevState => ({ books: [...prevState.books, book] }));
      BooksAPI.update(book, shelf);
    }
  };
```

Or better without mutating the state:

```
updateShelf = (book, shelf) => {
  this.setState(prevState => { 
    const booksCopy = prevState.books.filter(b => b.id !== book.id);
    booksCopy.push({ ...book, shelf });
    return { books: booksCopy } 
  });
  BooksAPI.update(book, shelf);
};
```

Comment: Spot on. Just added the API call to the `else` statement

Comment: @RichC I've updated an answer with the second example which doesn't mutate the objects. It simply removes an object from the list (if there was any) and ads it up again.

Comment: Nice one, I'll check it out